# how to stop MS edge from causing problems?

Tags: windows-10, malware, microsoft-edge

For sometimes I'm having trouble with Microsoft edge, explorer stops start menu don't opens, a program hang or take longer to start.. etc, I always find **msedge.exe** running multiple process, even if I restart explorer the problem mostly remain until I kill all edge processes.

1. I tried to remove edge using [these instructions](https://www.techradar.com/sg/how-to/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10) but didn't
   work, it was removed then installed again :(
2. I tried to stop it from running using policy editor at: User
   Configuration” > “Administrative Templates“, the policy “Don’t run
   specified Windows applications“ but also didn't stop it.
3. I suspected hackers using edge, used antivirus and anti malware scan
   but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prevent MS Edge from running is to install another browser, such as [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), and then set the new browser as the default. Edge should no longer open when clicking on a link.

If Edge still loads on login, you might need to remove edge from Startup and [set the Registry to prevent preloading](https://www.howtogeek.com/397718/how-to-prevent-microsoft-edge-from-preloading-on-windows-10/):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type `regedit`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Accept UAC to start *Regedit*.
- In the *Regedit* location bar, type, or copy and paste, `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft`.
- If the key `MicrosoftEdge` does not exist, right-click in the left pane on `Microsoft`, select *New > Key*` and create it.
- If the key `Main` does not exist, right-click in the left pane on `MicrosoftEdge`, select *New > Key*` and create it.
- If the value `AllowPrelaunch` does not exist, right-click in the *right* pane, select `New > DWORD (32-bit) Value` and create it.
- Double-click `AllowPrelaunch` and set it to 0 (zero).

This is far more effective than *removing* Edge, because after each Windows update, Edge would be reinstalled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-browser) is information on the group policy that manages the pre-launch instance of Microsoft Edge at Windows startup.  However, I must point out, Microsoft Edge is not the actual reason for the problems you describe.  Changing the default browser will just let the malicious software (if it exists on your system) to be used instead.

Comment: Thanks @drmoishe-pippik I already have FF default and Chrome installed, never used edge since the 1st installation of win10.

I done what you suggested it didn't stop Edge from launching, however it caused more edge processes to launch than normal, But it seems helped a bit when I ended the edge process tree all processes closed while it needed few time to close all of them.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but as long as you are a Windows's user, Microsoft is going to force you to accept their OS-integrated web browser without lube. That's been their policy since Internet Explorer. The decades of complaints and lawsuits accomplished nothing.

After all, how do you impose a punitive fine against a company that can shrug off a few billion dollar fine as a bad day and move on like nothing happened. The best you can hope as a Windows' User is using the reg settings and group policy to stop the bloody thing from pre-loading all the time.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 10 Version 1909 seems stable and don't have MS.Edge problem**
This is not a solution but containment to the problem, advanced task manager is able to totally terminate all edge tree unlike normal task manager, this total termination in one step prevent what initiate the edge processes from working, even restart the device didn't initiate the process "I suspect the setting explained above is working" but if the computer shut down for a period the edge processes will start and need to be terminated using super task manager, I'm using system explorer but also process hacker will do fine.

```
I'll update this answer if find permanent solution.
```

Comment: even rarely I looked at edge processes and found high memory or processor consumption, most of the time it behave like background processes but removing it improve computer response.

Comment: I sure wish it were possible. It's too integrated into the OS. They did that with IE, too.

Comment: And next will be ads in Windows Explorer -- looking at your own files: https://www.pcmag.com/news/microsoft-experiments-with-ads-in-windows-11-file-explorer . The only way out may be another OS.